# Button onclick leads to link

Tags: javascript, html, url, button

i want to know how to make it when a a button is pressed it will redirect you to a chosen url.
something like this:

```
<button onclick = "link()">Press to go to link!</button>

function link(){
//leads to url
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) to open in new tab.

```js
function link(){
  window.open('http://www.google.com');
}
```

```html
<button onclick = "link()">Press to go to link!</button>
```

**or**

```js
function link(){
  window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'; //Will take you to Google.
}
```

```html
<button onclick = "link()">Press to go to link!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<button class="btn" onclick="window.location.href = 'https://www.stackoverflow.com';">Click this link</button>
```

or

```
<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com"><button>Click this link</button></a>
```

This will direct the page to a expected link